# Wordpress Media folder is wrong

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to load media files in wordpress. My site url is set to sub-folder but in the link only localhost. Here is what i mean.

[image]

It suppose to be http://localhost/subfolder/wp-con....

I have try changing wordpress address and site url is

http://localhost/subfolder

I've also try adding

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR',  dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/subfolder/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL',  'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/subfolder/wp-content' );
```

Comment: Are those 404s from images within a post? Changing your wp-content directory will not update update existing links in your content.

Comment: they are within page. and link like <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/FB_ico.png">aaa</a>

Comment: You need to do a search and replace for the old URLs and replace them with the new ones. Try: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/  Also, relative paths aren't going to play well with permalinks.

Comment: is there any easy way because this will cause problem for production.

Comment: Using relative paths is not a solution. When you migrate to production you're going to have to update your links one way or another. I usually just use the search and replace tool linked to before.